# Change dynamic value demand on checkbox with knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, knockout.js

I've three elements: selectbox, checkbox, input.

```
viewModel.listTest= [{ value: '1', name: '10' }, { value: '2', name: '20' }];
<select class="form-control" data-bind="options: listTest, value: TestSelectBox, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'value', disable: TestTrigger()"></select>

viewModel.TestTrigger= ko.observable(false);
<input id="TestTrigger" type="checkbox" name="TestTrigger" data-bind="checked: TestTrigger" /> 

viewModel.inputTest = ko.observable('1');
<input name="inputTest " data-bind="value: inputTest , enable: TestTrigger(), valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
```

and I want to make: if checkbox is checked the value from input should pass to

```
viewModel.testValue
```

otherwise the value from select box should be pass to

```
viewModel.testValue
```

How can I do this ? I think I can use knockout method subscribe on checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a computed observable for testValue:

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="options: listItems, value: selectValue, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'name', disable: trigger()"></select>

<input id="TestTrigger" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: trigger" /> 

<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: input , enable: trigger()" />

<div>
    Your test value is: <span data-bind="text: testValue">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    var _selectValue = "";

    self.listItems = [{ value: '1', name: '10' }, { value: '2', name: '20' }];    

    self.trigger= ko.observable(false);

    self.selectValue = ko.observable();

    self.input = ko.observable('1');

    self.testValue = ko.computed(function() {
        if (self.trigger())
            return self.input();
        else
            return self.selectValue();
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/McCroskey42/5fg9eact/4/)

Each time that you update the select box, the checkbox, or the input, Knockout will call the function that you pass into ko.computed() and update whatever control is bound to it.

Under the hood, the act of evaluating the observables (trigger(), selectValue(), and input()) inside of a computed observable sets up the subscriptions to these three observables for you.  There is no need to manually subscribe to updates, which is a big part of the labor-saving magic of Knockout.

Answer (score 0):

give your select box an id like this:

```
<select class="form-control"  id = "selectInput"..>
```

Then try this:

```
viewModel.testValue = initialValue

$("#TestTrigger").on("change", function(){
    if(this.checked)
      viewModel.testValue = $("input[name='inputTest']").val()
    else
       viewModel.testValue = $("#selectInput").val()
});
```

Comment: The question specifically asked how to do this using Knockout.  Using jQuery to short-circuit Knockout's binding mechanism typically leads to grief.

Answer (score 0):

On a click event, call a function to update the value of the observable 'testValue'.

```
<input id="TestTrigger" type="checkbox" name="TestTrigger" data-bind="checked: TestTrigger, click: setTestValue()" />
```

In your viewmodel,

```
viewModel.testValue = ko.observable();

viewModel.setTestValue = function() {
    viewModel.testValue((viewModel.TestTrigger()) ? viewModel.inputTest() : viewModel.TestSelectBox()); 
    console.log(viewModel.testValue());
}
```